# Laravel Dusk deleting Input values after form confirmation

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-dusk

I am using Laravel Dusk for browser testing. I am still new to it and learning how it works. I am using a lot of JavaScript to help do what I need to do.

I have a form on a modal that needs to be filled, which I was able to do using JS. However, the validation fails because when Dusk presses the button to submit the field, it first clears the inputs, making the form throw errors, and therefore fail validation.

I've tried searching for others that have the same problem, but I can't find others. I haven't tried anything because there's no trace on where the problem originates.

```php
$browser->script('document.querySelector("#body-nav > div:nth-child(1) > select").selectedIndex=1');
            $browser->pause(5000);

            $insertJobTitle = <<<js
            document.querySelector("#body-nav > div:nth-child(2) > input").value="{$jobTitle}"
js;
            $browser->script($insertJobTitle);
            $browser->pause(1000);

            $insertDateTime = <<<js
            document.querySelector("#body-nav > div:nth-child(3) > input").value="2019-07-25"
js;
            $browser->script($insertDateTime);
            $browser->pause(1000);

            $insertEstimatedTimeToFill = <<<js
            document.querySelector("#body-nav > div:nth-child(4) > div:nth-child(1) > input").value={$numberHigh}
js;
            $browser->script($insertEstimatedTimeToFill);
            $browser->pause(1000);

            $insertNumberOfPositions = <<<js
            document.querySelector("#body-nav > div:nth-child(4) > div:nth-child(2) > input").value={$numberLow}
js;
            $browser->script($insertNumberOfPositions);
            $browser->pause(1000);

            $browser->script('document.querySelector("#body-nav > div:nth-child(5) > div:nth-child(1) > input").value=500');
            $browser->pause(1000);
            $browser->script('document.querySelector("#body-nav > div:nth-child(5) > div:nth-child(2) > input").value=200');
            $browser->pause(1000);
            $browser->script('document.querySelector("body > div.modal.fade.show > div > div > div.modal-footer > div > div > button.btn.btn-primary").click()'); //******** */
            $browser->pause(50000);
```

The expected result is to have Dusk submit the form. Error message is a JavaScript error saying `javascript error: Cannot read property 'click' of null` which is caused by the form timing out after the error in the inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as it turns out, I didn't need JavaScript as I thought. What was happening, is I was trying to use JS to insert text in an HTML element, which was actually a Vue component. When I would press the button to submit, it would not recognize the values.

The problem was that I was trying to insert data on a modal. I had a hard time using selectors with the modal. I ended up using this structure:

```
$browser->whenAvailable('body > div.modal.zoomin.show > div > div > div.modal-body', function($modal){
                $modal->click('body > div.modal.zoomin.show > div > div > div.modal-footer > div > div > label.ml-auto.mb-0.vue-js-switch > div');
                $modal->press('body > div.modal.zoomin.show > div');
            });
```

Solution, when you are accessing items in the modal, you have to use the whenAvailable method which then accepts a function, which is where you will reference the selectors of the items in the modal, but only after the modal is available.